Problems with external monitors and DisplayLink on Ubuntu 24.04
Linux noob here
Background info and specs:
I just installed Ubuntu on an old laptop. It's a Lenovo Ideapad 5 15IIL05. The hinges are broken, so I prefer to use it with an external display. I have an MSI mpg321urx and a BenQ ex2510 monitor. I use a Dockteck 7-in-1 USB-C Hub and StarTech.com USB 3.0 to 4K DisplayPort External Multi Monitor Graphics Adapter to connect both monitors to the laptop. The MSI is connected directly to the HDMI port of the hub, while the BenQ is connected to the adapter and then to the hub.
Issue:
When I connect the monitors at the login screen or when the laptop is shut down before powering on, everything works fine since I installed the DIsplayLink Ubuntu driver. But If I disconnect the monitors and reconnect them, or just connect them after I have logged in, then it has issues with my MSI monitor. It only uses the middle portion at a low res and the sides are just black.
The only thing that really works to solve the issue is logging out and logging in again, or logging in with Ubuntu on Xorg ( but that comes with its own issues).
My setup works fine on Windows and Mac.
when I first login

-IdeaPad-5-15IIL05:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 6840 x 2551, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-1 connected 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 700mm x 390mm
   3840x2160     59.98*+
   2048x1536     59.95  
   1920x1440     59.90  
   1600x1200     59.87  
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   2560x1600     59.94  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x720      59.75  
   960x600       59.63  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.90  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   3200x1800     59.96  
   2880x1620     59.96  
   2560x1440     59.96  
   2048x1152     59.90  
   1920x1080     59.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+4920+1471 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x720      59.97  
   960x600       59.63  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.90  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
DVI-I-1 connected 1080x1920+3840+240 right (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 540mm x 300mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x720      59.97  
   960x600       59.63  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.90  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
-IdeaPad-5-15IIL05:~$

After disconnecting and reconnecting

-IdeaPad-5-15IIL05:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 4024 x 1920, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+2104+840 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x720      59.97  
   960x600       59.63  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.90  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
DP-1 connected 1024x768+0+97 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      59.92*+
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   960x600       59.63  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.90  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
DVI-I-1 connected 1080x1920+1024+0 right (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 540mm x 300mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x720      59.97  
   960x600       59.63  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.90  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
-IdeaPad-5-15IIL05:~

